# React-leaflet custom components, how to extend Polyline from Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to extend a react-leaflet component so I can add custom variables to it.

I need to add an "id" to a Polyline (so when a user clicks on it, I can retrieve the id and make a server call behind to gather data on it). I had to do the same for the markers and found this workaround:

```
markers = nextProps.buses.map((bus, i) => {
  let iconCustom = new L.Icon.Default({internalId: bus.internalId});
  this.markersDirectAccess[bus.internalId] = {
    ...bus
  };

  return {
    lat: bus.latitude,
    lng: bus.longitude,
    popup: bus.busId,
    options: {icon: iconCustom}
  }
});
```

I'm not entirely sure if it's the right way to do it. But I'm stuck when it comes to the Polyline component.
I've found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123116) and I'd like to apply it to react-leaflet but I don't know how to do it. This is the current state of my extended component :

```
import L from 'leaflet'
import { Polyline } from 'react-leaflet'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export default class PolylineCustomId extends Polyline {
  static propTypes = {
    positions:  PropTypes.array,
  }

  createLeafletElement (props: Object): Object {
    return L.Polyline(props)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom component for this.  You can simply add a click handler for each polyline that will return it's id.  See this example:

```
render () {
  const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
  return (
    <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      />
      {this.state.polylines.map(polyline => 
          <Polyline
            key={polyline.id}
            positions={polyline.coords}
            onClick={() => alert('clicked ' + polyline.id)}
            />
        )
      }
    </Map>
  )
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/31euue73/1/

Comment: That did the trick ! I still wonder how to extend a leaflet component using the react lifecycle with react-leaflet though, but I'll accept this as an answer since it works :)